# SSLHandshakeException republish error with WebSphere 8.5 using Eclipse Mars

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibm-wdt

I am using WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse on Mars SR1. I am trying to republish my application on a remote WebSphere 8.5 server. I am running into a `SSLHandshakeException` error when I try to do an incremental publish.

A "Problem Occurred" dialog pops up with the following details:

> The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have
>   been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was
>   unable to start. Removal of the following application is completed: 
>   WebAppEAR Removal of the following application is completed: 
>   WebAppEAR Failure uploading archive to server: Upload retry limit
>   exceeded for file 
>   C:\Users\Administrator\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.ibm.etools.wrd.websphere.core\tmp1455916474993\TestEAR.ear.
>   Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl
>   could not build a valid CertPath.;

The only way I can republish my application is to remove it from the server and re-add it.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently a known problem with using WebSphere Application Server on Eclipse Mars with WebSphere Developer Tools. The technote below explains what's causing this problem and a few ways work around it.

IBM Technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21976357

Essentially, in Mars SR1 an EPP logging plugin was added, which conflicts with WebSphere Developer Tools. This affects the republishing on WAS V7, V8 and V85 using a secure profile with non-loose configuration (Run server with resources on Server). This includes remote servers, which always run with non-loose configuration and local servers that have that option enabled.

If you choose to disable the EPP logging plugin, please refer to the link below for the latest updates. Also, for those who are using Mars v2 now, please be aware the VM argument has changed slightly after Aeri v2 was introduced.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/Logging

Also, if you are using an existing workspace and the plugin wasn't disabled, you will have to delete the plugin directory manually. The folder is called "org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server" and it is located here: "workspace/.metadata/.plugins/".

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me whenever I use add or remove projects option to remove the projects and add it back again. When we remove the project from server using eclipse  sometimes it won't get remove from actual server. So when we add back again we get this exception. So make sure the project is uninstalled from server admin console when you remove it from server. If it is not, then uninstall forcefully from admin console.